# Como obter o tamanho de cada tabela no banco de dados?

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Através de uma `query`, como posso obter o espaço em disco que as tabelas (em um banco de dados) estão ocupando?

Consigo listar todas as tabelas utilizando o `sys.tables`, mas, e o tamanho?

```
SELECT NAME AS NomeTabela FROM sys.tables
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Referencia:*** [SQL Server: listar tamanho e número de registro de todas as tabelas](http://henriquecorrea.com/news/SQL-Server-listar-tamanho-e-numero-de-registro-de-todas-as-tabelas)

```
SELECT
    t.NAME AS Entidade,
    p.rows AS Registros,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS EspacoTotalKB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS EspacoUsadoKB,
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS EspacoNaoUsadoKB
FROM
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
GROUP BY
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY
    Registros DESC
```

também resposta [*SOEn - Get size of all tables in database*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892349/6797930)

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Um ***outra forma*** é com o comando [sp_spaceused](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188776.aspx):

<sub>**Observação:** ***[SQL Server version maior ou igual 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188776(v=sql.110).aspx)***.</sub>

```
sp_msforeachtable 'EXEC sp_spaceused [?]'
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

trazendo assim também a parte do tamanho dos índices.

***Referencia:*** [sp_spaceused (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188776.aspx)

Comment: A utilização do procedimento sp_MSforeachtable também é possível em versões anteriores ao SQL Server 2012. Só estou em dúvida se ele já existia antes da versão 2000. O mesmo para o procedimento sp_spaceused.

Comment: @JoséDiz a relação do versionamento é sobre [`sp_spaceused`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188776(v=sql.110).aspx) que é introduzido a partir do 2012 como descrito no link, vou editar a resposta e posicionar melhor sobre qual é o comando ... Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

No Galeria do Technet há vários scripts sobre como obter [table size](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/site/search?query=table%20size&f%5B1%5D.Value=table%20size&f%5B1%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=SQL&f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Text=SQL&ac=5).

Para análise visual, a forma mais simples é

```
-- código #1
execute sp_MSforeachtable 'execute sp_spaceused [?]'
```